# How can I remove paint from this window's aluminum track?

Tags: windows, paint

I recently purchased a house that has several layers of paint on the windows' aluminum tracks. (Wow! One bad paint job).

What's the best way to remove the paint, so that the windows will open and close easily?

[image: Paint on Aluminum window track]

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on deep in the track, but based on what I see in the photo, I'm not convinced the paint is what is making the window difficult to operate. In any case, use aircraft paint stripper to remove paint from aluminum..

Comment: Are these the style of windows that slide up and down?  I'd probably try a chemical paint stripper.  But might pay to ask if it's safe on aluminium.

Answer (score 1):

Paint thinner, a rag, and some elbow grease.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  This tells us **what** to use to remove the paint, but doesn't address **how** to remove it, especially the paint splashes that are hard to reach inside the tracks.  Could you please expand on your answer to cover the **how** part of the question?